# Does there exists on-time data for the EU, like there does for the US?

Tags: faa, datasets, flight-data-monitoring

I've recently found a fantastic [dataset](https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.aspx?gnoyr_VQ=FGK&QO_fu146_anzr=b0-gvzr) straight from the US government. It has detailed data including scheduled departure/arrival time vs actual departure/arrival time, taxi time, cancellation, for every single domestic flight in the US.

The EU is generally good about collecting data like this but I have not for the life of me been able to find it. I was wondering if anything similar exists for the EU.

Comment: If such dataset exists, it will be aggregated at [Eurocontrol level](https://www.eurocontrol.int/our-data) (each country in the UE has still a somehow independent ATC, with partial integration into Eurocontrol). Eurocontrol area corresponds more or less with the EU territory. Many datasets are also available at the [EU Open Data Portal](https://data.europa.eu/data/datasets?query=air%20traffic&locale=en&page=1)